# Oracle database response in Quarkus returns string of numbers

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, quarkus

Before I start, I must say that this is a work project and I'm not allowed to share all details. I'll try to include as much as I can without breaking the NDA. Thanks for your understanding.

I'm working on a Quarkus (2.3.0) application that communicates with an Oracle database. In it, I execute a stored procedure and should get a string in response.

After some fiddling, I was able to connect to the database and execute the stored procedure. However, the response seems to be encoded in some way that uses truncated ascii coding (leading zeroes dropped).

> 606578838769828362103232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232326065788783698295838465848583627975604765788783698295838465848583621032323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323260657883876982839583698462103232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323260657883876982476210323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232604765788387698283958369846210323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323260476578838769828362

At first, I assumed that each character code was two number long. However, other responses also contain letters which have character codes above 100.

Using the assumption of 2-character codes, I can parse the above response:

```xml
<ANSWERS>
                                                <ANWSER_STATUS>OK</ANWSER_STATUS>
                                                <ANSWERS_SET>
                                                    <ANSWER/>
                                                </ANSWERS_SET>
                                            </ANSWERS>
```

After some asking, the database admin told me that the database uses the `WE8ISO8859P15` encoding.

### The Question

How can I make Quarkus properly understand the `WE8ISO8859P15` encoding so that the `resultString` in the code below contains the response XML instead of a string of numbers?

### The Code

**application.properties**

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=oracle
quarkus.datasource.username=${DB_USERNAME:username}
quarkus.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD:password}
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//${DB_HOST:dbhost}:${DB_PORT:1521}/${DB_NAME:dbname}
```

**DatabaseCommunicator.java**

```
@Singleton
public class DatabaseCommunicator {

    @Inject
    AgroalDataSource dataSource;

    private static final String QUERY = "{ ? = call abc.SOME_WORDS.STORED_PROCEDURE_NAME(?) }";
    
    public Object getDetails(String objectId) {
        String resultString;

        try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection(); CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall(QUERY)) {
            String queryBody = "<objectId>" + objectId + "</objectId>";

            statement.setString(2, queryBody);
            statement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.CLOB);

            statement.execute();

            Clob resultClob = statement.getClob(1);
            resultString = readClob(resultClob); // Value of this String is the long number string.
        } catch (SQLException | IOException ex) {
            throw new DatabaseException("Exception while communicating with database", ex);
        }

        return resultString;
    }

    private String readClob(Clob input) throws IOException, SQLException {
        InputStream stream = input.getAsciiStream();

        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        int character = stream.read();

        while (character != -1) {
            buffer.append(character);
            character = stream.read();
        }

        return buffer.toString();
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
[...]
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-agroal</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-oracle</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.database.nls</groupId>
      <artifactId>orai18n</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc11</artifactId>
    </dependency>
[...]
```

Comment: Should be able to decode from 'iso-8859-15' to 'utf8'

Comment: I've added `InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, Charset.forName("ISO-8859-15"));` below the first statement of `readClob()` and then used that instead of `stream` for reading. However, that still results in the same string of numbers I'm afraid.

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51415859/jdbc-stream-of-clob-in-oracle-12-2-database-gives-wrong-encoding

Comment: I am wondering whether it is OK to use an ascii stream for iso-8858-15?  `InputStream stream = input.getAsciiStream();`  If you figure out how to fix this, please make an answer as I think this will be of use to other people.

Comment: There's also a `getCharacterStream();` method which returns the same string of numbers. I couldn't find any other methods that return data.

Answer (score 1):

I had expected the JDBC driver to automatically decode the response from the database. However, that turned out not to happen.

Instead, I found the relevant code in the JDBC driver that helped me decode it myself. For this, I used the `quarkus-jdbc-oracle` dependency that is a part of the Quarkus BOM:

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc11</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Then, I used the built-in decoding logic that's already present in the driver to convert the string of numbers to something I can use:

```java
import static oracle.sql.CharacterSet.WE8ISO8859P15_CHARSET;

import oracle.sql.converter.CharacterConverterFactoryJDBC;
import oracle.sql.converter.JdbcCharacterConverters;


class Example {
    private String readClob(Clob input) throws IOException, SQLException {
        InputStream stream = input.getAsciiStream();

        CharacterConverterFactoryJDBC converter = new CharacterConverterFactoryJDBC();
        JdbcCharacterConverters converters = converter.make(WE8ISO8859P15_CHARSET);

        byte[] bytes = stream.readAllBytes();
        return converters.toUnicodeString(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    }
}
```